# Mysql own order saved in a column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a mysql table that looks like:

```
id    name
0     Test1
1     Test2
2     Test3
3     Test4
4     Test5
```

What i would like to have is, to define a userdefined order. So it should be possible to
1) insert a new row at a defined position
2) change the position of an existing row

i know that this is possible by using REPLACE INTO

The problem is that i don't want to change the primary key (id) for this as it is part of other Joints. So my intention was to add a new colum "ordering" - But how could i then manage it to get the functionality i want? Or is there a completely different solution for this?

example of added column:

```
id    name     ordering
0     Test1    0
1     Test2    1
2     Test3    3
3     Test4    4
4     Test5    5
5     Test6    2
```

Answer (score 0):

That's almost exactly how we do it on our site with a column called position, although we use 1 based rather than 0 based position..

The logic for changing a position is actually fairly complicated.. so when we drag-drop change a position in a grid view we send an ordered array of all the item ids from the group (in their new positions) to the server and update the positions for every row (some stay the same).

We also only allow adding of rows to the front (set position 1 and shift all existing positions up 1), or the back (set position as max + 1). The user can then drag-drop the row to the position they want in a grid view.

This will probably be refactored at some point, but isn't causing issues at the moment and the code is fairly light.